# How to find the complement of the domain from $f(x)=\sec \frac{\pi}{3}-\csc^2 4x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

> Let the function $f(x)=\sec \frac{\pi}{3}-\csc^2 4x$.
> Find the complement of the domain of the function $f(x)$.

The given choices in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\left\{(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{16}/n\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}\\
2.&\left\{(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{4}/n\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}\\
3.&\left\{(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}/n\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}\\
4.&\left\{\frac{n\pi}{4}/n\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}\\
\end{array}$

Gee in this question I really don't know where to begin with. My workbook doesn't explain well this topic. Could someone help me how to solve this without much fuss?.

I wish I could offer more than just that. But I'm lost at the very beginning.

The only thing which I do recally is that secant can take all reals minus each $\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}$. Thus I believe I have discount these but I don't know how to do that.

All and all I don't know how to put these ideas together in order to solve this question. Can someone **guide me on what should be done first?** Please try to explain each line so I can understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

First, recall that the domain is the set of $x$ values that you're allowed to plug in - that give you a well defined expression.The term $\sec\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$ is a constant, and so it will not affect the domain; no matter what value of $x$ you plug in, that term will be the same, so it won't have any effect on the domain. This means that what you're really looking for is the domain of $-\csc^2(4x)$. Now, recall that $\csc(x) = \frac{1}{\sin(x)}$, so

$$-\csc^2(4x) = \frac{-1}{\sin^2(4x)}$$

This is the quotient of two things. The quotient of two things is only undefined when the denominator is $0$. This means that $x$ is not in the domain if and only if $\sin^2(4x) = 0$. Now, solve that equation, and the set of $x$ that you get will be the $x$ that are not in the domain, which should allow you to identify the correct option.

Answer (score 0):

The complement of the domain is precisely the set where the given expression is not well defined.

To find out such set, observe that
\begin{align*}
\csc^{2}(4x) = \frac{1}{\sin^{2}(4x)}
\end{align*}

where the denominator cannot be zero. This means that we have to exclude the values of $x$ such that
\begin{align*}
\sin^{2}(4x) = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow \sin(4x) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 4x = k\pi\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x = \frac{k\pi}{4}
\end{align*}
where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Based on the given options, we deduce the right answer is given by the number (4).

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The input to secant is $\frac{\pi}3$, it is not a function of $x$.

We just have to handle $\csc^2 4x$ and it is not well defined when

$$4x = n\pi.$$

Comment: thanks, just edited.

Answer (score 0):

$\sec(\frac\pi3)$ is constant.
$\csc(y)$ and $\csc^2(y)$ are defined for all $y\ne n\pi$.
Here letting $y = 4x \ne n\pi\Rightarrow x\ne\frac{n\pi}{4}$

So the complement of the domain is $\{\frac{n\pi}{4} |n \in \Bbb Z \}$